# automate csv import in mysql db in linux environment

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

Is there a way to have a .csv imported into a SQL Table automatically in mysql db?  I know how to do it manually, but there is a situation where a .csv is exported nightly from PeopleSoft and we want that imported automatically into SQL Table in linux environment. plese give me a sample script to do that.. If there's a way, can anyone point me in that direction (I'm not a SQL expert)!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating Stored procedure,
Write load csv query into SP.
Create Event to call SP.
I hope this helps.

```
 CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `load_csv_event`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 23 DAY_HOUR
    DO CALL my_sp_load_csv();
```

Alos, You can directly create an event and write a load query into it.

Comment: thanks for the response...but we can't call the load query in mysql sp..can u pls tell me any alternative way to do it..any dump code if u have..

Comment: hi priyanshu..how  directly create an event and write a load query into it...plse tell any way to do that..

Comment: Run a windows task scheduler.

Create .bat file  with Load query and run with scheduler

I have not done it, but should work.
No harm in trying new stuff.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion priyanshu...but i m working in unix environment..not on windiws

Answer (score 0):

You could create a crontab job, for example:

```
* * * * * /path/to/load_script.sh
```

Where load_script.sh may be like (do not forget make it executable):

```
#!/bin/bash
IMPORTED_FILE_PATH=/path/to/your/imported/file.csv
TABLENAME=target_table_name
DATABASE=db_name
TMP_FILENAME=/tmp/${TABLENAME}.cvs
# do nothing if imported file does not exist
[ -f "$IMPORTED_FILE_PATH" ] || exit 0
# if temporary file exists, then it means previous import job is running. Also do nothing
[ -f "$TMP_FILENAME" ] && exit 0
# Move it to tmp and rename to target table name
mv "$IMPORTED_FILE_PATH" "$TMP_FILENAME"
mysqlimport --user=mysqlusername --password=mysqlpassword --host=mysqlhost --local $DATABASE $TMP_FILENAME
rm -f "$TMP_FILENAME"
```

It is just an example (not tested). You should add error handling, logging, etc.
Also look at manual of [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html)